# how to set path to popovertemplate in my solution?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap popovertemplate (ui.bootstrap.popover) but the solution does not see the template:

```
<span
    popover-template="./mytemplate.html"
    popover-trigger="mouseenter"
    ng-bind-html="somevalue">
</span>
```

What is the right way of specifying the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to specify path in single quote `popover-template="'./mytemplate.html'"`